# Using Spring Boot RestTemplate-Client to submit Json to remote SpringBoot Microservice

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

I need to use SpringBoot Client-Side  RestTemplate  to submit a simple json String,
to a SpringBoot Microservice on a remote machine.

ex: - http://:8080//valid?jsonValue={"user":"scott","psswd":"tiger"}

Thx in advance.

Comment: Please share code from any attempts that you tried, also you need to post the jsonValue as a request body payload not as a query param

Comment: I found the answer to submit via body and rest template thx for the tip